# Extract columns from pdf

Tags: regex, pdf, pdftotext

I would like to extract data from my bank account statements.

The operations are displayed like that in the pdf:

[image]

Using [pdftotext](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftotext), I get data like this:

```
03/01/2011 03/01/2011 XXXXXX
0400262553990000000000713596003
03/01/2011 03/01/2011 PAIEMENT CB 0201 XXXX
XXXX
XXXXXXXX
04/01/2011 04/01/2011 PAIEMENT CB 0201 XXXXX
XXXXXXX
//some other operation in the same format

XXXXXX //my account balance
31,00
32,70
68,00
//some other amounts
```

I would like to be able to reliably identify all operations with its correct amount.

So:

- is there alternatives to pdftotext ?
- is there any options in pdftotext wich could help me, for example in formatting correctly columns in the output ?

With some regular expressions:

```
var operations= pdftext.match(/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}\ [0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}[^\n]*/g);
var amounts = pdftext.match(/\n[0-9]+\,[0-9]{2}\n/g);
```

I get corrects results but I see some issues:

- I did not succed to capture the secondary lines. I would have to tell to stop before a new date.
- I looked over several text results of all my statements, but it is possible that the format has changed over time.

Comment: Perhaps, regex way is too hard, see [this attempt](https://regex101.com/r/tF1iX0/1).

Comment: Possible other solution: my bank offers downloading account data in a variety of formats, not only PDF but as CSV as well. (I suppose asking for a test PDF is not an option ...)

Comment: My bank offers also this service, but just for a few monthes. I have just the pdf files for old statements.

Comment: You are right, a little bit complicated! As I understand you are using a negative lookahead to stop capturing before the next line with two dates.

Answer (score 1):

Regex are great but I suppose that all reports you have are maintaining almost the same table and columns locations on the page.

So I would first data column by column (or maybe row by row) by specifying the crop rectangle in `pdftext` command line parameters: `-x 10 -y 10 -W 100 -H 300` so it will return text from the cropped area only. Please notice that these command-line options are available in `poppler-utils` version only:

```
-x number
Specifies the x-coordinate of the crop area top left corner
-y number
Specifies the y-coordinate of the crop area top left corner
-W number
Specifies the width of crop area in pixels (default is 0)
-H number
Specifies the height of crop area in pixels (default is 0)
```

The PDF resolution is `72` Dots Per Inch so you may easily find coordinates of column or row measuring by printing PDF as is and measuring in inches and multiplying by 72 or by setting PDF Viewer to display PDF with 100% zooming, making a screenshot and measuring locations from screenshot.

Also, there is the cross platform open-source [Tabula](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula) project designed to extract data from tables in PDF files, maybe it will work better for your purposes (though the setup could be more complicated comparing to `pdftotext`)

Comment: This would simplify the process, as it limits the text output. But I finally used `pdftohtml -xml`, which has not this option, but allow a better text selection.